# React not rendering component within if block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a protected route component, using firebase, I have the following setup

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

import firebase from 'firebase';

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: 'xxxxxx',
    authDomain: 'xxxxxx',
    databaseURL: 'xxxxxx',
    projectId: 'xxxxxx',
    storageBucket: 'xxxxxx',
    messagingSenderId: 'xxxxxx',
});

class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {}

    render() {
        const { component: Component, layout: Layout, redirect, auth: isAuthorized, ...rest } = this.props;

        if (!this.props.hasOwnProperty('auth') && !this.props.hasOwnProperty('layout')) {
            return <Route {...this.props} />;
        }

        const template = Layout ? (
            <Layout>
                <Component />
            </Layout>
        ) : (
            <Component />
        );

        if (!this.props.hasOwnProperty('auth') && this.props.hasOwnProperty('layout')) {
            return <Route {...rest} component={() => template} />;
        }

        if (isAuthorized) {
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
                if(!user) {
                    console.log(user)
                    return redirect ? <Redirect to={{ pathname: redirect }} /> : <Route render={() => <div>Unauthorized</div>} />;
                }
            })
        }

        return <Route {...rest} render={() => template} />;
    }
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

My routes are setup like this, which allows me to pass in if a route should be private or not

```
import Route from './containers/ProtectedRoute';
 <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
    <Route path="/private" auth={true} component={PrivatePage} />
    <Redirect to="/" />
  </Switch>
```

What I would expect to happen is, when visiting `/private` I should trigger the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` call and on returning `null` I should then trigger the redirect logic.

Instead I am still hitting `return <Route {...rest} render={() => template} />;`

Meanwhile the `console.log` within the firebase call is outputting null

Comment: If I am not mistaken here, you _always_ need to check _`if (isAuthorized) {...}`_ first.

Comment: `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` is asynchronous, so the return statement inside your `if (isAuthorized) { ... }` is never used in the rendering, so `return <Route {...rest} render={() => template} />;` will always be run in this case.

Comment: @Tholle details email e reg e audzieci e

Comment: I thought as the return statement is within the callback of ```onAuthStateChanged``` it would still run?

Comment: The render method is synchronous, so no asynchronous logic will work, sadly.

Comment: Ah I understand, thank you, I foolishly thought this was async, so I assume I should move this to a lifecycle hook and setup the flow in a different fashion?

Comment: Yeah, that is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` is asynchronous, so the return statement inside your `if (isAuthorized) { ... }` is never run.

You could instead put this logic in `componentDidMount` and store the result of the lastest change in your component `state` and use that.

**Example**

```
class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
  auth = firebase.auth();
  state = { user: this.auth.currentUser };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      this.setState({ user });
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  render() {
    const {
      component: Component,
      layout: Layout,
      redirect,
      auth: isAuthorized,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;
    const { user } = this.state;

    if (
      !this.props.hasOwnProperty("auth") &&
      !this.props.hasOwnProperty("layout")
    ) {
      return <Route {...this.props} />;
    }

    const template = Layout ? (
      <Layout>
        <Component />
      </Layout>
    ) : (
      <Component />
    );

    if (
      !this.props.hasOwnProperty("auth") &&
      this.props.hasOwnProperty("layout")
    ) {
      return <Route {...rest} component={() => template} />;
    }

    if (isAuthorized && !user) {
      return redirect ? (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: redirect }} />
      ) : (
        <Route render={() => <div>Unauthorized</div>} />
      );
    }

    return <Route {...rest} render={() => template} />;
  }
}
```